# Run IceWM in Ubuntu minimal installation?

Tags: boot, software-installation, lightdm, ubuntu-minimal, icewm

I am building a custom Ubuntu distro to suit the needs of an aging Dell Latitude (XP era). I want the end result to be similar to the AntiX distro, but with all the added benefits of Ubuntu.
I did a fresh install of the Ubuntu minimal installation with no desktop environment included. From there, I install IceWM and LightDM via the command line.

All I want is to be able to boot up Ubuntu, reach the LightDM login screen, and log into IceWM. The problem is this; when I reboot, Ubuntu hits a blank screen and freezes. It does not respond to keyboard input, and I cannot even access the command line. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is there a step I missed someplace? Is this build even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For minimal installations I recommend using a minimal tool named `xinit`.

First of all disable or remove lightdm.

Then make sure you have installed `xorg` related stuff, packages like:

```
xserver-common
xserver-xorg
xserver-xorg-core
xserver-xorg-input-all
xserver-xorg-video-all
```

then install `xinit`:

```
sudo apt install xinit
```

Now after login use:

```
startx
```

it should bring your IceWM up, if it didn't work for your then in your home directory run:

```
cp /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc .xinitrc
```

open `.xinitrc` using an editor:

```
nano ~/.xinitrc
```

and comment all lines (put a `#` at the start of each line laking `#`).

then add:

```
exec icewm-session
```

and save the file, now run `startx` and it should work fine.

---

As an alternative to `lightdm` you can install `slim`, start the service or reboot the system, then login using your credentials and you should be fine to go.

Comment: I apologize for the late response (I had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch). Your instructions worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @bowen3 You're welcome, you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful to you by clicking on the gray tick ;)