# Lightest possible Ubuntu install for running a single graphical app in a VM

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu

I want to run Crashplan in a proxmox VM. The options are Ubuntu or Windows (no other linux distros supported - can confirm it failed in Mint).

There's no headless version of the software so I need some kind of gui.

So I want the bare minimum Ubuntu install that's able to run this single app. I tried Xubuntu and Lubuntu but even those come with snap and various apps that I don't want (this is not a powerful proxmox host). I also want it to auto log in and launch the app.

What's the best approach?

Comment: The best approach is to not use Ubuntu, frankly. Ubuntu isn't designed to be a lightweight system but there are dozens of other distributions which are. You could use something like Arch or Manjaro if you are an experienced user and just install what you want, or try things like Damn Small Linux or Puppy Linux or anything else you find when you search for "lightweight Linux".

Comment: I know that Ubuntu Mate has an option for a minimal installation. You won't get most of the programs, and can remove things like Firefox and snapd as needed.

Comment: Lubuntu is the lightest Ubuntu flavor and comes, by default, without any snap. However, even if snapd is installed, is consumes very little resources only unless you start one of more snaps. And it is possible to remove snapd and still have a fully usable system.
But non  of the Ubuntu flavors is really light, the difference between the various desktop environments is not that significant. Running Lubuntu on a single core is already challenging.

Comment: Install Ubuntu Server. Then, install a window manager like ice-wm. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IceWM and https://askubuntu.com/q/941376/124466

Comment: I can confirm what's already been provided; though you've not provided any release details which can make a significant difference, thus we're limited to generic advice.  Lubuntu is *lightest*, however if you want a very *light* system I'd not use a desktop install, but start with a server install & add WM etc only according to your tastes/needs.  Ubuntu Core is also *lean* but it's more limited with regards GUI options.  (Lubuntu comes with no snaps, or `firefox` as snap depending on release details; but `snapd` for most recent releases yes).

Comment: You do not want to full Desktop installs that include all the apps, just the gui. Lightweight Desktop environment
Ubuntu Server + lxde or openbox or fluxbox or xfce Like `sudo apt-get install lxde` after server install.